# Replace array elements with onclick

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to display new list of shuffled array on `onclick` but my code is just appending the new shuffled array below the previous list. My code is:

```
function shuffleArray() {
        var array = ['1','2','3','4'];
            for (var i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
                var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
                var temp = array[i];
                array[i] = array[j];
                array[j] = temp;
                }


    for (i=0;i<array.length;i++) {
            var span = document.createElement('span');
            span.innerHTML = array[i];
            span.onclick = shuffleArray; //calls the same function
            var div = document.createElement('div');
            div.appendChild(span);
            document.body.appendChild(div);
            }
    }
```

Current output:

```
    2
    1
    4 // if I click here then results gets appended below
    3
    3
    2
    4
    1 // if I click here then results gets appended below
    2
    1
    4
    3 // and so on
```

Desired output: I want the page content to get updated with new array elements, each time I click some array element.

Comment: thats because you use the append function....

Comment: I had probably figured that out long before but if I don't use `append` function, then `onclick` doesn't works.

Comment: Place your new elements in an outer wrapping div, and then prior to appending new children call `wrapping_div.innerHTML='';`. Either that, or store each div you append to an array and then, when you need to remove them, step through the array using `body.removeChild(div);`.

Comment: Can you show an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What follows is the simple version, but this is prone to memory leaks because you are using `.onclick` and are not removing those references before destroying the elements with `.innerHTML='';`

```
var wrapping_div = document.createElement('div');

document.body.appendChild(wrapping_div);

function shuffleArray() {
  var array = ['1','2','3','4'];
  for (var i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    var temp = array[i];
    array[i] = array[j];
    array[j] = temp;
  }
  wrapping_div.innerHTML = '';
  for (i=0;i<array.length;i++) {
    var span = document.createElement('span');
    span.innerHTML = array[i];
    span.onclick = shuffleArray; //calls the same function
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.appendChild(span);
    wrapping_div.appendChild(div);
  }
}

shuffleArray();
```

A better way is http://jsfiddle.net/NCUDv/2/:

```
var wrapping_div = document.createElement('div');

document.body.appendChild(wrapping_div);

function shuffleArray() {
  var i, j, temp, span, div,
      c = wrapping_div.childNodes, 
      l = c.length,
      array = ['1','2','3','4'], 
      k = array.length;
  for (i=k-1; i>=0; i--) {
    j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    temp = array[i];
    array[i] = array[j];
    array[j] = temp;
  }
  for (i=l-1; i>=0; i-- ) {
    c[i].firstChild.removeEventListener('click', shuffleArray);
    wrapping_div.removeChild(c[i]);
  }
  for (i=0; i<k; i++) {
    span = document.createElement('span');
    span.innerHTML = array[i];
    span.addEventListener('click', shuffleArray);
    div = document.createElement('div');
    div.appendChild(span);
    wrapping_div.appendChild(div);
  }
}

shuffleArray();
```

Comment: sorry, i didnt see you post the same answer 1 min before ;).... your second way would be pure dom scripting, but is definitley the slower one

Comment: @ThorstenArtner'Austria' is your approach more efficient than the second method?

Comment: its the same pebbl posted in his first way, perhaps he could give a link about the memory leaks generated by not removeing the eventListeners, i never noticed this. its stuff for the JS garbage collector

Comment: @ThorstenArtner'Austria' ~ Ah np :) Using `.innerHTML` will be faster (precisely because it doesn't wipe things safely), I have used it myself in the past for small areas to be blanked (mainly for elements without event listeners). However, in any code that is going to repeat itself over and over and that uses event listeners (like this), memory problems should be avoided at all costs. What may be a best of both worlds would be to not keep creating and destroying the elements, just change their `innerHTML` value directly i.e. 1 becomes 4, 2 becomes 3 and so on.

Comment: @pebbl did you ever have problems by not removing the eventListeners, or could you please give a link to an science article about the memory leaks

Comment: @ThorstenArtner'Austria' I've had numerous leak related problems over years of developing JavaScript sites and applications. It is also the reason why modern browsers now come with very good manual leak detection abilities i.e Chrome; because it is difficult to tell exactly what a browser will fall prone to. Leaks occur when the GC is unable to tell if it should remove something from memory or not, meaning you can't just rely on it without being aware of it's shortcomings. http://javascript.info/tutorial/memory-leaks http://www.vladalexandruionescu.com/2012/08/javascript-memory-leaks.html

Comment: Leaks can occur with circular references, closures, and by the use of assigning **inline/attribute event handlers** or event handler closures that are not removed -- assigning anything directly to a DOM Element is always risky (if not removed later). After building many large js apps it is mine and many others advice that if you create something, you should tear it down correctly... By doing so it helps you build better code. Obviously on small scale projects it is down to your own discretion. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13190337/avoid-memory-leak-usage-javascript

Comment: i only had memory leaks because of closure functions, i make some tests to see if i have to change my programming style in this direction, i dont think this is a problem in modern browsers but i will test .. have a nice day

Comment: @ThorstenArtner'Austria' If you are using `addEventListener` then you are most likely fine (as long as your closures are safe from keeping large references alive), it is still best to remove them if possible. If you are using `.onclick` or `onclick="jsFunc()"` and the like, then yes, I would change to using `addEventListener`. Best testbed would be any of the Internet Explorers, other browsers do suffer, but to lesser degrees.. and again, only for code that is going be iterated again and again. For one offs there is no worry :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var container=document.createElement ("div");
document.body.appendChild (container);

function shuffleArray() {
    var array = ['1','2','3','4'], l=array.length;
    var i,j,tmp;
    for (i = l - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[j];
        array[j] = temp;
        }

    var span;
    container.innerHTML="";
    for (i=0;i<l;i++) {
        span = document.createElement('span');
        span.innerHTML = array[i];
        span.onclick = shuffleArray; //calls the same function
        container.appendChild(span);
        }
    }
```

edited

```
var container=document.createElement ("div");
document.body.appendChild (container);

function shuffleArray() {
    var array = ['1','2','3','4'], l=array.length;
    var i,j,tmp;
    for (i = l - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[j];
        array[j] = temp;
        }

    var p;
    container.innerHTML="";
    for (i=0;i<l;i++) {
        p = document.createElement('p');
        p.style.margin="0px";
        p.innerHTML = array[i];
        p.onclick = shuffleArray; //calls the same function
        container.appendChild(span);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Here, the elements are displayed horizontally. I wanted it to be displayed horizontally.

Comment: Do you mean vertically then change the span to p

Comment: Sorry, vertically and probably with no spaces between 2 vertical elements! Incase of p, it creates vertical spaces.

Comment: this is stuff of CSS. margin Property