# Should I remove event listeners in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

My site works on jQuery + AJAX and has the only javascript file, which loads once when a user opens any page, so I'm used to add event listeners to all elements like: `$(document).on(...)`.

In a while I'd noticed that there are too many `.on(...)` in the code, and I got afraid. I'd taken 9 pills and forced it to delete useless listeners every time when a user click on a link / back button.

```
function page_reload(){
   if(c.r == 'http://example.com/page1'){
      $(document).on('click', '#send', func.send);
      $(document).on({mouseenter: func.me, mouseleave: func.ml}, '#chan');
   }else{
      $(document).off('click', '#send');
      $(document).off('*', '#chan');
   }
}
```

So is there any sense? Maybe a big number of listeners do some bad thing I don't know about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you attach a listener to an event, it does take memory and it can (if totally unchecked) cause memory related issues. In my experience, it is best to employ `cleanup` methods in your objects that, when a certain event fires, you use your `.off()` methods to unregister your event listeners.

The particular logic to these types of methods will vary depending on your project but something of the form:

```
var MyApp = {
  cleanup: function cleanMyApp(event) {
    this.off('#myId1', myMethod1);
    this.off('#myId2', myMethod2);
  }
}

$('document').on('ready', function() {
  $(document).on('importantEvent', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // if you need to
    MyApp.cleanup();
  });
  // or 
  $('#elem').on('something', MyApp.cleanup);
});
```

So yes, having too many listeners registered at a time can cause issues but you can monitor memory usage with your browser's dev tools and the like. In particular you can run out of stack (and heap?) memory and possibly crash the browser.

There is also a great answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13190337/avoid-memory-leak-usage-javascript) on dealing with these kinds of issues.